# Microsoft windows phone 8: AdControl ads showing in emulator but not on device

Tags: windows-phone-8

this is my code

```
<UI:AdControl Height="80"
              Width="480"
              Margin="0,315,0,4"
              AdUnitId="Image480_80"
              ErrorOccurred="AdUnit_ErrorOccurred"
              ApplicationId="test_client"
              Visibility="Visible"
              Name="adControl1"
              />
```

this is my code

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);          
}

void AdUnit_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ad error " + e.Error.Message.ToString());
}
```

when i run it in emulator, it appear but in the device, it does not appear.

and also when i add the real `ApplicationId` and  `AdUnitId` (e.Error.Message = "No ad available.")

Comment: is it required publishing the app in the store ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a account in Microsoft PubCenter and create an ad unit for your app by registering your app in pubCenter, then you will get the ApplicationID and  the AdUnitId from the Pub center. Then you ad controller code should be like this,

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="test_client" 
              AdUnitId="Image480_80" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Height="80" Margin="0,72,-24,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" 
              IsAutoCollapseEnabled="True" 
              IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"/>
```

Replace the `ApplicationId` and `AdUnitId` from the values you get from [pubCenter](https://pubcenter.microsoft.com). When you run this on the emulator pubCenter test ad will appear after some time. Actual ads only available for devices.

Note. Even if you ApplicationId and AdUnitId is correct depending on where your device is located the ads will not show. Some times ads are not available, then the `ErrorOccurred` event will fire and if you want you can catch that and use another AdController such as `AdDuplex` to display ads when pubCenter ads are not available.

Take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMa1M4h_Tp4) from youtube on how to use AdDuplex and how to use it with Microsoft Ad Control

Comment: i did this but when i replace with the real id it's not work on the device . is it required publishing the app in the store ???

Comment: Does it work on the emulator? I mean does the test Ad shows, sometimes depending on the location you are in ads are not available. So even if everything is correct the ads will not show.

Comment: yes it work in emulator .  how can i solve the location problem ??

Comment: you can't, thats the way it is, take a look at the edited answer, use adDuplex as a back up ad Controller when pubCenter ads are not available.